# Como carregar uma pagina de Erro 404 para o site e outra para aplicação HTACCES?

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess

.htacess do site

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    # Redirecionamento http to https SSL Protocol

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    # END WordPress

    RewriteEngine On
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

.htacess do Sistema

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]


RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /https://www.meusite.com.br/aplicacao/404.html
```

Comment: a página 404.html não está carregando. Será que é porque estou testando no localhost? ou não tem nada haver?

Comment: já consegui fazer funcionar para o site, mas para a aplicação não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas diretivas estão erradas:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /http://localhost/www.meusite.com.br/404.html
```

E:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /http://localhost/aplicacao/404.html
```

Os formatos aceitos são:

- ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"`
- `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html`
- `ErrorDocument 404 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html`
- `ErrorDocument 404 http://error.example.com/server_error.html`

E no caso do ultimo ele será redirecionado.

No seus códigos está sobrando um `/` na frente, na verdade é bem provavel que você queira passar é o documento **e não uma URL**, o correto então seria passar o caminho completo interno, por exemplo se no `DocumentRoot` ou no `VirtualHost` do apache é configurado algo como `/` para o primeiro seria:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /www.meusite.com.br/404.html
```

E para o outro seria:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /aplicacao/404.html
```

Comment: o htacess do site já está funcionando o problema está no segundo, o da aplicação.

Comment: @Ramiro não estão em formato corretos amigo, aonde no virtualhost esta o da aplicacao?

Comment: o htacess da aplicação está dentro da pasta da aplicação. O do site, está dentro da pasta public_html